# Angularjs retaining session

Tags: angularjs

i'm using asp.net webapi. Authentication is basic authentication by Thinktecture library.

When the user logs in, the username and password is stored in a session cookie using `$CookieStore`.

i'm adding the credentials to the header for every get request as below

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic '+$cookieStore.get('__RequestVerificationToken');
```

The problem is, i have to call this before every get request.  Is there a way that the Angular will  automatically add this to the header and when the response is 401, then the user should automatically redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using config for setting http headers site-wide?:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider, $cookieStore) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Authorization'] = 'Basic '+ $cookieStore.get('__RequestVerificationToken');
}]);
```

Please note that in my example I specifically added the default Authorisation header only to `GET` requests.

---

Regarding the second part of your question, you need to define a response interceptor, which will capture each http response, listen for status code of 401 and broadcast an appropriate event (or redirect directly to login page) when it happens:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.config(['$httpProvider', '$location', function($httpProvider, $location){

    var interceptor = ['$rootScope', '$q', function($rootScope, $q) {
      var broadcasted;

        function success(response) {
        return response;
      }

      function error(response) {
        if (response.status === 401) {
          $rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
          // or $location.url('/login');
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          return deferred.promise;
        }
        // otherwise
        return $q.reject(response);
      }

      return function(promise) {
        return promise.then(success, error);
      };

    }];

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);
}]);
```